# Can you continue logging errors while buffering output in php?

Tags: php, error-logging, output-buffering

My php.ini file has the following options:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
...
log_errors = On
```

So without output buffing, all errors are logged. Is there a way to still log NOTICES, WARNINGS, and ERRORS to my error_log while using ob?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, take a look at [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Comment: AAHHHH shoot my bad i had an '@' sign in front of an include. i'll flag for removal

Comment: No need, the question is still valid and answer might help someone.